# Oracle Autovue 3d image extraction with Zoom

Tags: image, oracle, extract, cad

I am using Oracle Autovue Server to extract 3d images from CAD file. We call Autovue server with CAD file and Autovue server extract the images in different formats like Isometric, Left, Right, Top etc. I would need the image should be extracted with Zoom fit. But I can not find any solution.

Following are the codes that I am using for zooming functionality:

```
bean.getController().get3DController().zoomFit();
```